# the August 13, 2021 change

Tags: github

when i try to (git clone https://github.com....), they ask me for my username and password then its show this :

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/thelinuxchoice/blackeye/'

I tried to change the password and everything but it's always the same thing, please help :(

Comment: follow the instructions for connecting to github with ssh, there is a link on the page you referenced. If all you did was change a password, you have not followed the instructions!

Comment: have you tried to read information on url you posted?

Answer (score 4):

The trick in the password is a joker trap. In fact, the password that is being asked from you there is not a password, but a token. It is generated in the developer settings. In fact, this article provides a link to the answer you need. If anything here https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token
"$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).